# Razor renderpartial exception - expected '}"

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

In my code:

```
@foreach (var post in Model.Posts)
{
    Html.RenderPartial("ShowPostPartial", post);
}
```

i have an excepion on RenderPartial line.

error CS1513: } expected.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is this code inside another `{...}` pair? That's when I hit this issue. And I think leaving out the @ before `foreach` fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

For completeness, here's another way of causing this:

```
@if(condition)
{
    <input type="hidden" value="@value">
}
```

The problem is that the unclosed element makes it not obvious enough that the content is an html block (but we aren't *always* doing xhtml, right?).

In this scenario, you can use:

```
@if(condition)
{
    @:<input type="hidden" value="@value">
}
```

or

```
@if(condition)
{
    <text><input type="hidden" value="@value"></text>
}
```

Comment: We use the `<text>` wrapper a lot in this situation.

Answer (score 2):

This is basically the same answer that Mark Gravell gave, but I think this one is an easy mistake to make if you have a larger view:
Check the html tags to see where they start and end, and notice razor syntax in between, this is wrong:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{ 
   <div class="divClass">
     @Html.DisplayFor(c => c.SomeProperty)
}
</div>
```

And this is correct:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{ 
   <div class="divClass">
     @Html.DisplayFor(c => c.SomeProperty)
   </div>
}
```

Again, almost same as the earlier post about unclosed input element, but just beware, I've placed div's wrong plenty of times when changing a view.

Comment: This fixed this for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten this issue with Razor.  I'm not sure if it's a bug in the parser or what, but the way I've solved it is to break up the:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm()) { 
<h1>Example</h1>
@foreach (var post in Model.Posts)
{
    Html.RenderPartial("ShowPostPartial", post);
}

}
```

into:

```
@{ Html.BeginForm(); }
<h1>Example</h1>
@foreach (var post in Model.Posts)
{
    Html.RenderPartial("ShowPostPartial", post);
}

@{ Html.EndForm(); }
```

Comment: Is there any reason you're not using Using?
@using (Html.BeginForm()) { // content // }... That's your problem I believe

Comment: No, I just forgot it. :D  Edited to fix.

Comment: BTW your problem is that you have a @ before your foreach. Also, I prefer @Html.Partial instead of Html.RenderPartial... But that's just me :P

Comment: @Linkgoron: after closing the braces, you'll need another `@`.  I'll add an html element to avoid further confusion.

Comment: I was talking about your first example. The one with the using. You don't need another @ before your foreach, as you're already in a code block.

Answer (score 0):

MY bad. 
I've got an error in the partial view.
I've written 'class' instead of '@class' in htmlAttributes.

Answer (score 0):

The Razor parser of MVC4 is different from MVC3. Razor v3 is having advanced parser features and on the other hand strict parsing compare to MVC3.

--> Avoid using server blocks in views unless there is variable declaration section.

Don’t : \n
`@{if(check){body}}`
Recommended : 
`@if(check){body}`

--> Avoid using @ when you are already in server scope.

Don’t : `@if(@variable)`
Recommended : `@if(variable)`

Don't : `@{int a = @Model.Property }`
Recommended : `@{int a = Model.Property }`

Refrence : https://code-examples.net/en/q/c3767f